# Querying Amazon MWS from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, amazon-mws

I am trying to query the Aazon MWS to get price of a product by ASIN. But I am not being able to convert the query in Google Apps Script so I can use with UrlFetchApp. Please help.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyPriceForASIN.html﻿

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the example [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) to line up with a portion the AWS example you linked:

```
function sendHttpPost() {


   var payload =
   {
     "ASINList.ASIN.1" : "1933890517",
     "AWSAccessKeyId" : "AKIAEXAMPLEFWR4TJ7ZQ",
     "MWSAuthToken": "amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE"
     // and so on for all of the name value pairs that make up the query
   };

   // Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
   // an HTML form. (We do not need to specify contentType; it will
   // automatically default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   // or 'multipart/form-data')

   var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload
   };

   UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/upload_form.cgi", options);
 }
```